# Number of complete cases by combination of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, data-wrangling

I have a large database with hundreds of columns and would like to know for every possible combination of two columns how many complete cases there are.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(V1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 5),
                 V2 = c("a", "b", "c", NA, NA),
                 V3 = c(1, 5, NA, 4, 5),
                 V4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

# > DT
#    V1   V2 V3 V4
# 1: NA    a  1 NA
# 2: NA    b  5 NA
# 3: NA    c NA NA
# 4:  3 <NA>  4 NA
# 5:  5 <NA>  5 NA
```

What I expect is something like this:

[image]

With the diagonal indicating the number of complete cases for that variable. I thought of using some kind of for loop but it gets very cumbersome. Perhaps a function/solution already exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `crossprod` with `is.na`

```
> crossprod(!is.na(DT))
   V1 V2 V3 V4
V1  2  0  2  0
V2  0  3  2  0
V3  2  2  4  0
V4  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: Great option with crossprod